# escaping the ${ sequence in terraform CUSTOM_DATA bash script

Tags: bash, terraform

I need to be able to pass to the linux startup bash script the following:

```
echo "  image: ${DOCKER_IMAGE}" | tee -a /setup/mgmt.yml
```

and I have tried about 9 different suggested ways:

- $${DOCKER_IMAGE} resulting in no output at all
- "$${DOCKER_IMAGE}" inside the quoted string, same result
- "${local.dollarsign}${local.dockertag}" resulting in no ouput
  and various permutations.
  locals was stuff like:

```
locals {
    dollar = "$"
    dockerimage = "{DOCKER_IMAGE}"
    dockertag = "{{DOCKER_TAG}}"
}
```

Comment: You have to use single quotes, or even better use a YAML aware tool such as yq.

Comment: Are you just trying to write the string literal to file?  If so, just escape your dollar with a backslash: `echo "  image: \${DOCKER_IMAGE}"`

Comment: Oh, I probably misunderstood what gets interpolated where here, since this is within Terraform. Never mind my comment 

Comment: Thanks to everyone for looking. When I use: echo "  image: '$${DOCKER_IMAGE}'" , the result in the yml file is:  image: ''

Comment: The following works: echo '  image: $${DOCKER_IMAGE}' 
Single quotes prevent any kind of interpolation by Terraform

Comment: @Wolfgang to explain why your solution works:
there are two levels at which `${...}`gets interpreted here: first, there is the "bash-level", so you need the single quote (`'`) to prevent your shell to try to interpolate your string. Then, there is Terraform interpolation, which can be prevented by using `$${...}` instead of `${...}`.

Here is why you need both the double dollar sign and the single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly what you are doing, it seems like you are using Terraform's string template syntax to generate a bash command which itself wants to write the literal string   `image: ${DOCKER_IMAGE}` to a file.

This means you have two levels of escaping to contend with: Terraform's template interpolation syntax and bash's interpolation syntax.

Terraform's escape syntax is to double the dollar sign, like `$${`, and doing that would then make the string `${DOCKER_IMAGE}` visible to bash. But then bash will try to replace that with an environment variable called `DOCKER_IMAGE`, which is presumably not set and so bash would replace it with an empty string.

You can escape *bash's* interpolation by placing the whole string in single quotes, which disables interpretation of any metacharacters other than the closing `'` inside the quotes.

Putting that all together:

```
  terraform_thing = <<-EOT
    echo '  image: $${DOCKER_IMAGE}' | tee -a /setup/mgmt.yml
  EOT
```

Having multiple layers of interpretation like this always inevitably gets pretty confusing. If at all possible I would suggest trying to remove some of these layers, such as by having Terraform itself generate this YAML document using its `yamlencode` function so that bash won't be involved. However, if you can't avoid using a shell intermediary here then the above should hopefully work.